# UIScrollView with fade effect with nativescript vuejs

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I would like to know if it's possible to have UIScrollView with fade effect with nativescript please ?

For example : https://medium.com/@luisfmachado/uiscrollview-with-fade-effect-246e332e8b24

I read the documentation https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/scroll-view/, but I don't found this information.

I would like this result for example :

[image]

Do you have an idea please ? Thank you

I have no idea how can I put the native code in my component

```
<template>
    <ScrollView class="scroll" orientation="vertical" row="1" ref="scrollView">
        <StackLayout marginLeft="10" marginRight="10" class="container-verses">
            <StackLayout horizontalAlignment="center">
                <Label textWrap="true" textAlignment="center" text="hello" color="#FFFFFF" fontSize="20"/>
                ...
                <Label textWrap="true" textAlignment="center" text="hello" color="#FFFFFF" fontSize="20"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name    : 'FadeScrollView',
        computed: {},
        methods : {
            //
        }
    };
</script>

<style lang='scss' scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: You can overlay a gradient that goes from white to transparent. The way to do it depends on your layout.

Comment: Thank you @IgorR. but I would like to use an image in background

Comment: The link you provided as an example shows text that's faded on top. Can you update your question with an example that you're looking to do? Perhaps draw something to explain it?

Comment: @IgorR. I updated my post with an example

Comment: You could port the exact native code and create a new {N} component extending ScrollView, override create native view to return an instance of FadeScrollView.

Comment: @Manoj I'm confuse, do you have an example please ? I have no idea how can I put the swift code in my component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you translate Swift into NativeScript

```
import { isIOS } from "@nativescript/core/platform";
import { ScrollView } from "@nativescript/core/ui/scroll-view";

let FadeScrollViewImpl;

if (isIOS) {
    FadeScrollViewImpl = UIScrollView.extend({
        fadePercentage: 0.2,
        gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer.new(),
        transparentColor: UIColor.clearColor.CGColor,
        opaqueColor: UIColor.blackColor.CGColor,

        topOpacity: () => {
            const scrollViewHeight = this.frame.size.height;
            const scrollContentSizeHeight = this.contentSize.height;
            const scrollOffset = this.contentOffset.y;
            const alpha = (scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight || scrollOffset <= 0) ? 1 : 0;
            return UIColor.alloc().initWithWhiteAlpha(0, alpha).CGColor;
        },

        bottomOpacity: () => {
            const scrollViewHeight = this.frame.size.height;
            const scrollContentSizeHeight = this.contentSize.height;
            const scrollOffset = this.contentOffset.y;
            const alpha = (scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight || scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight) ? 1 : 0
            return UIColor.alloc().initWithWhiteAlpha(0, alpha).CGColor;
        },

        layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()

            this.delegate = this;
            const maskLayer = CALayer.new();
            maskLayer.frame = this.bounds;

            this.gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(this.bounds.origin.x, 0, this.bounds.size.width, this.bounds.size.height);
            this.gradientLayer.colors = [this.topOpacity, this.opaqueColor, this.opaqueColor, this.bottomOpacity];
            this.gradientLayer.locations = [0, NSNumber.alloc().initWithFloat(this.fadePercentage), NSNumber.alloc().initWithFloat(1 - this.fadePercentage), 1];
            maskLayer.addSublayer(this.gradientLayer);

            this.layer.mask = maskLayer
        },

        scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView) {
            this.gradientLayer.colors = [topOpacity, opaqueColor, opaqueColor, bottomOpacity];
        }
    });
}

export class FadeScrollView extends ScrollView {
    createNativeView() {
        if (isIOS) {
            return FadeScrollViewImpl.new();
        } else {
            return super.createNativeView();
        }
    }

    attachNative() {
        if (!isIOS) {
            super.attachNative();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just have to register the element to start using it in template

```
Vue.registerElement('FadeScrollView', () => require('./fade-scrollView').FadeScrollView)
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=DACsPf)

Comment: Awesome @Manoj !! Thank you so much !!